# Dúvida Python URL

Tags: python

Ola Comunidade sou iniciante em python e tava querendo criar uma ferramenta so que em certa parte obtive duvida.

Fiz Esse Pequeno Codigo que filtram as tag `<img>` da Pagina.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    t=input('Digite o Nome do Filme:')
    ano=int(input('Digite o Ano do Filme:'))

    if ano==1:
      req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'&language=pt-BR')
      bs=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml') 
      print(bs.find_all('img')) 
    else:
      req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query='+t+'%20y%3A'+str(ano)+'&language=pt-BR')
      bs=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml') 
      print(bs.find_all('img'))
```

Ai fiz essa outra parte que pegar o link da imagem e exiber ela no console.

```
import io
import os
import requests
import tempfile
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_url = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500_and_h282_face/dKxkwAJfGuznW8Hu0mhaDJtna0n.jpg'

buffer = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=1e9)
r = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    downloaded = 0
    filesize = int(r.headers['content-length'])
    for chunk in r.iter_content():
        downloaded += len(chunk)
        buffer.write(chunk)
        print(downloaded/filesize)
    buffer.seek(0)
    i = Image.open(io.BytesIO(buffer.read()))
    i.save(os.path.join('.', 'image.jpg'), quality=85)
buffer.close() 

plt.imshow(i)
plt.show()
```

Ai queria saber como faço pra variavel `img_url` pegar a url do `print(bs.find_all('img'))` automaticamente. 
Ou se tem alguma Biblioteca pra Isso.

Answer (score 1):

A função `find_all()` retorna uma lista de elementos, logo, é possível pegar os atributos dos elementos da seguinte forma:

```
# Retorna o valor do atributo 'alt' do primeiro elemento da lista
print(bs.find_all('img')[0]['alt'])
# Resultado: The Movie Database (TMDb)
```

Se você quiser pegar todos os links dentro de **data-src**, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req=requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query=the%20flash&language=en-US')
bs=BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser') 
res = bs.find_all('img')

for link in res:
    try:
        print(link['data-src'])
    except:
        print('Elemento não possui data-src dentro de <img>')
```

Note que existem elementos que não possuem o atributo **data-src** dentro da tag , portanto faz-se necessário o uso do `try, except`.